# Use factory inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently struggle in understanding the modules-principles in AngularJs.

I have 3 files:

- App
- Controller
- Factory

I want to use the factory inside my controller:

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
```

controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function () {
    ...
}
```

factory.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    factory('test', function () {
        return 'Just a test';
    });
```

How can my controller know from `test`-factory?

Comment: That's a VERY BASIC question that answer you will find on the first documentation page you land on, but you made no effort to find the answer for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inject it as dependency as you do for 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', ['test',function (test) {
 ...
]};
```

PS it's the same as doing this, but work when you uglify your code

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController',function (test) {...};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject your factory in to wherever you want to use it. In this case your controller.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function ('test') {
    ...
}
```

Also it is worth remembering that if you have multiple modules, you can inject them on each other and use their services in each other through dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You code is perfectly fine. You just need to inject the factory into your controller. See bellow

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', ['$scope','test',function ($scope, test) {
 // Do your stuff here with test
]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection!

Take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Inject the factory to the controller. Then you can use the factory service from your controller.